# LookUp not matching properly

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

So, I have a problem in Report Builder that is just driving me absolutely crazy.

I have two dataset; one called DS_Grades and the other DS_Pupils. I want to do a simple LookUp based on PupilID, a field that is in both datasets, and return a grade from DS_Grades into a Matrix based on DS_Pupils.

The formula I am using is:

=LookUp(Fields!PupilID.Value, Fields!PupilID.Value, Fields!Grade.Value, "DS_Grades")

I have confirmed that:

1) DS_Grades has the right PupilIds
2) There are actually values in the Grades field
3) Both PupilID fields (I.E. in both datasets) are definitely Integers and not text.

Moreover, if I add a calculated field to DS_Grades called "test" and populated with the value 208301, which is a valid PupilID, then I can enter the below formula and it works fine:

=LookUp(208301, Fields!test.Value, Fields!Grade.Value, "DS_Grades")

So, the LookUp itself must be matching properly, which means that the PupilID fields must be causing the problem, but I have quintuple freaking checked them and they definitely have the right values, in the right format. I am at a total loss as to why SSRS thinks that they don't match.

Help please!

Comment: Interesting discovery; when I filter DS_Grades to just PupilId 208301, it works correctly FOR THAT PUPIL ONLY. Unfiltered, it works for nobody, including that Pupil.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Some filtering was at Dataset Level (instead of query where I normally do it) that was throwing the whole thing out of joint. Removed that, and it's fine.